# Angular for loop failing due to undefined value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

I have following `for loop` within angular
  ...

```
for (var m = array1.length -1; m < array1.length; m++) {
 var value1 = array1[m];

...
```

Here, `array1` is getting value as 'undefined' which is causing the code to fail.
Please suggest how to make sure that the code is not failing if `array1` is `undefined`

I am using angular 1.5

Comment: If this is angular 1.5, you should remove the angular tag.

Comment: if (array1) or what you expect?

Comment: if `array1` is 'undefined' then make `var m` as 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be to check for a condition and then execute the code if array1 is defined and is an array.

```
if(array1 && Array.isArray(array1)){
   for (var m = array1.length -1; m < array1.length; m++) {
   var value1 = array1[m];
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply initialize your array...

```
array1 = []
```